# Tornado PyMongo product wishlist

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

I am writing a Tornado app in which a user can maintain his products wishlist. There are two collections, `users` and `products`. As the names imply, the `users` collections will contain users info and the `products` collections will contain the URLs.

Typically a `user` document in `users` collection will contain the following fields:

- `email_id`
- `name`
- `tracked_products`

The `tracked_products` here is a list which maintains the wishlist. It contains the `ObjectId` mapped to URLs in `products` collection. To make it clear, when two users add the same product URL, in their respective user documents instead of containing the URL, they will have the `ObjectId` of this URL, which is the ID of the URL in the `products` collection.

To find tracked_products of a specific user:

```
    search_user = user_db.find_one({'email_id': user_email})
    search_user['tracked_products']
```

above will return to me list of `ObjectId`s.

To add a product URL to the user's wishlist:

```
product_doc = product_db.find_one({'url': url})
if not product_doc:
    # code needs to be added here to get product name from url
    product_id = str(product_db.insert({'product_name': 'iPad', 'url': url})
else:
    product_id = product_doc['_id']
user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$addToSet': {'tracked_products': ObjectId(product_id)}})
```

The following is the code when user wants to remove a URL from his wishlist. Do note that he will send the `ObjectId` instead of the URL, he intends to remove. This may seem less intuitive. The user will actually never know the `ObjectId`s, but the page rendered to him which displays the wishlist, will make call when user wants to delete the URL (am I clear here?):

```
user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$pull': {'tracked_products': ObjectId(product_id)}})
```

And here is my actual Tornado app code. I am not using any templating as of now, will add that later. Also ignore the repeated `user_db = self.application.db.users` statement which is present in all handlers (which should not, may app can have this variable). And one more thing: I access the current logged in user's email ID every time by a cookie.

Is there any way to avoid this? Can I have some global variable which stores user email ID every time the user is logged in?

```
class ProductsDisplayHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        user_db = self.application.db.users
        search_user = user_db.find_one({'email_id': user_email})
        self.write(str(search_user.get('tracked_products', None)))


class ProductAddHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self, url):
        user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        user_db = self.application.db.users
        product_db = self.application.db.products
        product_doc = product_db.find_one({'url': url})
        if not product_doc:
            product_id = str(product_db.insert({'product_name': 'iPad', 'url': url}))
        else:
            product_id = product_doc['_id']
        user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$addToSet': {'tracked_products': ObjectId(product_id)}})


class ProductDelHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self, product_id):
        user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        user_db = self.application.db.users
        user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$pull': {'tracked_products': ObjectId(product_id)}})
        self.redirect('/products')
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try editing your BaseHandler like this

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        self.user_db = self.application.db.users
```

and then call the  following in your other Handlers

```
self.userdb.update({'email_id': self.user_email},
```

Basically the prepare function is called right at the beginning of the request
for more information you can look at the [tornado docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare)